# Apache starts spinning when there are 10 people using a website

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, apache-2.4

I have Apahce 2.4.18 running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have multiple users working on a website. But it seems that after a while the website will start spinning and the page does not load.

It seems that there are some setting that is not allowing many users to be on at the same time.

I increased the value of `ThreadsPerChild` in te httpd-mom.conf from 150 to 1000.

And changed the `mpm_worker_module` to the following

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit             250
    StartServers             10
    MinSpareThreads         75
    MaxSpareThreads        250 
    ThreadsPerChild         32
    MaxRequestWorkers      400
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
    ThreadLimit              64
    MaxClients             8000
    MaxRequestsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>
```

but not sure how can I figure out the issue at this point?

What can I do to see what is happening with Apache?

Comment: Why are you using a port on non-native platform in a production environmemt in the first place. That is the question. Rhetorical, though.

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking me here